# Search data using Timestamp datatype in Oracle Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp

I have table Alert_Logs in which there are 2 columns `KPI_DEF_ID` and `TIMESTAMP`. The `TIMESTAMP` column is of `timestamp` datatype. I want to search a data using timestamp column in oracle sql where clause. I tried below query but it returns nothing.

```
Select * from ALERT_LOGS WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = 1000571 and TIMESTAMP = to_timestamp('17.10.15 00:02:58','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: That means there are no rows with that timestamp and kpi_def_id. Why do you think something it is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare timestamp with date. Timestamp also have milliseconds. Assuming TIMESTAMP is of type timestamp likely this will work

```
Select * from ALERT_LOGS WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = 1000571 and to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') = '17.10.15 00:02:58';
```

This is how timestamp is represented.

SQL> select to_timestamp('02.12.15 08:40:54', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

### TO_TIMESTAMP('02.12.1508:40:54','DD.MM.YYHH24:MI:SS')

02-DEC-15 08.40.54.000000000 AM

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju No. It is not efficient solution. I wouldn't do that as it would degrade the performance. Since, using TO_CHAR would suppress any regular index. The best approach is to use range condition as I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Lalit Good point. But if there is index on KPI_DEF_ID, it might not be big problem. In some cases there might not be indexes on timestamp columns.

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju Most reporting systems have indexes on the timestamp column, the whole point in having a timestamp column is to filter rows based on the timeline.

Answer (score 2):

> and TIMESTAMP = to_timestamp('17.10.15 00:02:58','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')

Since your column data type is **timestamp**, it would have more elements than **datetime**.

Also, the **equality condition** does not match any rows. You need to use a **range condition**.

For example, to get all the rows having timestamp between `2 AM` and `3 AM`:

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= to_timestamp('17.10.15 00:02:00','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')
AND   TIMESTAMP <  to_timestamp('17.10.15 00:03:00','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

The good part using a **range condition** is that it will be **efficient** in terms of **performance**. Using **TO_CHAR** would suppress any regular **index** on the **timestamp column**. The range condition would do an **index range scan**.

Comment: can you please tell me lalit how to use range condition ? And you are correct lalit equality condition is not matchin rows.

Comment: @Rahul See the example in the answer.

Comment: @Rahul You mean you do not want rows matching with that exact timestamp? And return all other rows?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, just use `<>` OR `!=`